# Remove-Item Vs [System.IO.File]::Delete()

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, powershell-workflow

I have the following code in an Azure Runbook:

```
$pathToDownloadedBlob = 'C:\depId-20150904032522\SevenZipSharp.dll'
if ((Test-Path $pathToDownloadedBlob) -eq $true)
{
    try
    {
        Remove-Item -Path $pathToDownloadedBlob

    }
    catch
    {
        write-error "Could not delete $pathToDownloadedBlob. - $($error[0])"
        exit
    }
}
```

When I use `Remove-Item` I get this error:

```
4/7/2015 2:14:14 PM, Error: Remove-Item : The converted JSON string is in bad format.
At DavidTest:45 char:45
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Unauthor... Boolean force):ErrorRecord) [Remove-Item], 
InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JsonStringInBadFormat,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

When I use `[System.IO.File]::Delete($using:path)` instead, I get this error:

```
4/7/2015 2:22:48 PM, Error: Exception calling "Delete" with "1" argument(s): "Access to the path 'C:\Deployment\SevenZipSharp.dll' is denied."
At DavidTest:46 char:46
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
```

I know I don't have permission to delete the file.
However, why is it complaining about a JSON string when I use `Remove-Item`?

EDIT:
Note this only happens in Azure Automation. However I wasn't truly able to replicate this in Powershell ISE locally because I have permission to files I wish to delete.

---

UPDATE:I just realised this is only happening for .dll files. If I try to delete a .7z file it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that this is due to the serialization / deserialization of the object being passed between the PowerShell Workflow context, and the InlineScript Workflow Activity, which runs in a separate process by default.

Are you always passing in a `[System.String]`, or are you sometimes passing in a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` object? If the latter, then you'll probably want to reference the `FullName` property, rather than passing in the object itself to `Remove-Item`.

I'm not 100% sure that this is what you're running into, but it's worth discussing.

By the way, as a best practice, always explicitly name your parameters, so other people understand what you're doing. Your call to `Remove-Item` doesn't include the `-Path` parameter, by name, because it's positionally at 0. Of course, this isn't a good thing to take for granted when you're asking for help. Better to be verbose.

Hope this helps at least a bit. By the way, is this problem unique to Azure Automation Runbooks, or does it also exist in locally executed PowerShell Workflows?

**Edit**: This code seems to work just fine for me locally.

```
workflow test {
    $Path = 'C:\dsc\srv01.xml';
    InlineScript { Remove-Item -Path $using:Path; };
}

test
```

Comment: yeah but did you simulate not having permission to that file?

Comment: and you tested that locally. It works fine for me locally as well. But not on Azure.